# Listing words from array with must letters using linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I'm trying to list the words with the most letters. I'm new to LINQ and am a bit confused.

This is my code:

```
string sentence = "write wwww five cat com LINQ queries to do the following good abba";
string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');

 IEnumerable<string> query3 = words
            .Where(n => n)        
            .OrderBy(n.Length).Reverse;

        IEnumerable<string> query33 = query3
           .Where(n => n.First.length)
```

Comment: ``words.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Trim().Length)``

Comment: And how I can select all the words that have the same length of the first word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use directly use `OrderByDescending`:

```
string sentence = "write wwww five cat com LINQ queries to do the following good abba";
string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
IEnumerable<string> query3 = words
                     .OrderByDescending(n => n.Length);
```

And you do not need the second query, only the first one (`query3`).

The `OrderByDescending` takes the lambda parameter to decide how to order the `IEnumerable` in descending order. You just need to input the `Length` of the string in the `IEnumerable` as the parameter for ordering.

**Update:**

*(This is based on the comment, not the question)*

If you want to take all the words in the same length with the first one, you have some choices actually. But, suppose you want to continue from the ordered sequence, I would use `Max` and `TakeWhile`:

```
string sentence = "write wwww five cat com LINQ queries to do the following good abba";
string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
IEnumerable<string> query3 = words
                     .OrderByDescending(n => n.Length);
int max = query3.Max(n => n.Length);
var query4 = query3.TakeWhile(n => n.Length == max);
```

Comment: And how I can select all the words that have the same length of the first word?

Comment: you could check your first word by `First()` if you want. But in that case I would first get max length  by `Max()` and then use the value to get the rests of the words by `Where`

Comment: @coco OK, sample added

Comment: @coco actually depending on what you want, you may not even need to order by descending if your aim is just to get the words with max length... you could use `Max` and `Where`, or even `GroupBy` will do immediately in a single LINQ. It depends on your need.

Comment: @coco anyway, the fastest way to do that is actually by using `GroupBy` and `First()` you could get the words with max length in a single LINQ

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> orderedWords = words.OrderByDescending(p=>p.Trim().Length).ToList();
```

Comment: And how I can select all the words that have the same length of the first word?